# PHP-print the difference in two strings

Tags: php, comparison

I am using `strcasecmp()` to compare two strings, how do I print out if there is a different in a string.

for example:

```
$string1 = "Hello World;";
$string2 = "Hellow World";

if(strcasecmp($string1, $string2) ==0){
     echo $string1;
     echo $string2;
}else{
     echo #the difference;
}
```

should print out:

```
";" "Hellow"
```

Comment: Where does `HelloW` come from? That's not in either string?

Comment: Shouldn't it just print `;` and `w` because the first string has an extra `;` and the second string has an extra `w`?

Comment: Is this your homework? Is the error detection by word or character? The example output is unclear though.

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in that will do this. You have to write your own loop. It's called programming, get used to it.

Comment: If it is by word, you can minimize the effort by using [explode()](http://php.net/explode) function.

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-diff.php

Comment: You can also use this (but its not in default php) [link](http://web.archive.org/web/20080506155528/http://software.zuavra.net/inline-diff/)

Comment: @Bob0t, worth noting that requires the extension xdiff to be installed and isn't going to return the output the OP wants.

Comment: `explode()` will not work with an empty delimiter. You would have to use `str_split()`.

Comment: @sudosoul not empty if its a space no ?

Comment: Yes space will work. I misread and thought OP wanted to do character by character comparison, hence my answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
<?php
$string1 = "Hello World;";
$string2 = "Hellow World";

/* Transform each string into character array */
$s1 = str_split($string1);
$s2 = str_split($string2);

/* Let's print them just so you can see */
print_r($s1);
print_r($s2);


/* Check if the character from first string, exists in string 2 */
foreach ($s1 as $key1 => $value1) {
  if (($key2 = array_search($value1, $s2)) ) { //If the character from the first string, is found in the second string...
   if (strcasecmp($value1, $s2[$key2]) == 0) {  //Make sure the case matches
      unset($s1[$key1]);        //Remove the matched character from the first string.
      unset($s2[$key2]); //Remove the matched character from the second string.
    }
  }
}

/* Note that because 0 also means false, we need to check
 * if the characters at index 0 match or not */
if (strcasecmp($s1[0], $s2[0]) == 0) {
  unset($s1[0]);
  unset($s2[0]);
}

$differences = array_merge($s1, $s2);
if ($num_differences = sizeOf($differences)) {
        echo "Found $num_differences differences in the two strings. They are: \n";
        print_r($differences);
}
```

The code above checks to see if each character in string 1 exists in string 2. If the character does exist, we remove it from both arrays, so that any characters not found will be leftover in each array.